# Javascript InnerHTML does not work with Quasar/VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, quasar-framework

Basically, I want to create tables dynamically based on the items inside 'counts' array below.
Number of tables can change as well as its contents (removed from this example for simplicity).

Here is my divContainer, this is where innerHTML will be appended.

```
<div id="divContainer" style="padding: 3%;">
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
<script>
const columns = [
  { name: 'desc', align: 'left', label: 'data', field: 'desc' },
  { name: 'tag', align: 'center', label: 'name', field: 'name' },
  { name: 'length', align: 'center', label: 'len', field: 'length' },
  { name: 'value', align: 'left', label: 'val', field: 'value' }
]

var counts = ['5', '6', '7', '8']

var container = document.getElementById('divContainer')
counts.forEach(function (count) {
   container.innerHTML += '<div id="panel-' + count + '" class="text-h4 q-mb-md">' + count
   container.innerHTML += ' \
     <q-table \
       :columns="columns" \
       :rows-per-page-options="['100']" \
       row-key="name" \
       dense \
       separator=horizontal \
     > \
       <template v-slot:body="props"> \
       </template> \
     </q-table> \
    '
     container.innerHTML += '</div>'
   })
</script>
```

However, this doesnt appear to be working. The first div works fine (outputs the content of the array) but the `q-table` part is not working.
No errors but no output as well.
Perhaps innerHTML does not support q-table (Quasar or VueJS framework)

I also tried inserting the html chunk inside a `<script>` but it gives me an error message:

```
<script id="table" type="text/javascript">
  <q-table
    :columns="columns"
    :rows-per-page-options="['100']"
    row-key="name"
    dense
    separator=horizontal
  >
    <template v-slot:body="props">
    </template>
  </q-table>
</script>
```

Help, anyone?

Comment: Not exactly related, but `+=` does not append, it's an assignment. It's just a shortcut to `var = var + add`. Opening the DevTools tells you why the `<q-table` part fails, there certainly should be an error message complaining about an infinite string literal.

Comment: also, is the `</script>` tag closed before the closing of the function's body `})`?

Comment: Woops, that is just wrong copy-paste.. Sorry.. Updated it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the script is executed the generated HTML seems to be right:
[image: generated html got from browser developer tools]

It is probably a matter of vue.js not parsing the code generated via `innerHTML`: I think you should generate it via `v-for`.